# Can a row be added to the middle of a JPanel that uses GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, gridbaglayout

I have a `JPanel` that uses `GridBagLayout` to layout components.  I just had the idea of adding a row in the middle of the grid based on what the user is doing.  Is this possible with `GridBagLayout`?  I can know the `gridy` of the row above the row to be added.  I am currently just removing them from the layout and adding in the row and all of the rows after.  It is a very slow process.

Comment: Layout managers are meant to allow you to display components for your GUI and not intended to be a dynamic component unto itself.  You can keep doing what you're doing, but eventually I think you will find it time wasted.  I've not known anyone to change a layout once it was already rendered. I have been wrong before. I'd be curious to know of anyone who has attempted this and succeeded.

Comment: Is it possible? Probably, how will depend on how your componets are already laid out...

Comment: I just did a quick trial of adding each of the elements incrementing the gridy by 2 instead of one.  This leaves blank row to be filled.  then I think I can add and remove the components in this row.  The other option I just thought of was to add all of the possible rows and use setVisible to have them show up where they are needed.

Comment: Using setVisible() works well, I wished I would have thought to do something outside the scope of the gridBagLayout before I posted the question.

Comment: *" I just had the idea of adding a row in the middle of the grid based on what the user is doing."*  Add a panel to that row when making the GUI.  Give it a `CardLayout`.  As other components/parts are needed, add them to the card layout and flip cards.